# Page Validation not functioning with JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have requiredFieldValidator for a dropdownlist inside a panel. If there is no data selected in the dropdown btnSubmitReport works fine to validate and display *. Once data is selected and btnSubmitReport is clicked to display data it still works fine. Now if you unselect the dropdown and hit btnSubmitReport it does not do validation anymore. This is because first time btnSubmitReport_Click is clicked, it checks to see if Page.IsValid and calls JavaScript code, but subsequent calls are just calling JavaScript code and btnSubmitReport_Click is not being called to see if the page is Valid. Please suggest. Here is the sample code on the aspx page:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testValidator.aspx.cs"
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" Inherits="textXslt.testValidator" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script src="Styles/Reports.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <h3>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Text="Reporting Filter"></asp:Label>
    </h3>
    <div style="text-align: right">
        <input id="lnkShowFilter" type="button" value="Show Filter" onclick="ShowF()" class="btn" />
        <input id="lnkHideFilter" type="button" value="Hide Filter" onclick="HideF()" class="btn" />
    </div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="divFilter">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplMain" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBusiness" runat="server" Text="Business Division" CssClass="chkbox" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBusiness" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true"
                                                CausesValidation="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBusiness_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                ValidationGroup="grpSubmit" Width="350px">
                                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="-1">--- SELECT ---</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>Orange</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>Apple</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>Mango</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBusiness" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlBusiness"
                                                Enabled="true" ToolTip="Please select a Business." ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="-1"
                                                ForeColor="Red" CssClass="required" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="grpSubmit">
                                            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
                <hr size="1" />
                <div style="text-align: center">
                    <table style="width: 10%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnHome" runat="server" Text="Home" OnClick="btnHome_Click" CssClass="btn" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitReport" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitReport_Click"
                                    ValidationGroup="grpSubmit" CssClass="btn" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <div id="divResult">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplGrid" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                Here go Results of grid
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
    protected void btnSubmitReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            btnSubmitReport.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:SubmitF();";
        }
        //then do rest of the processing to display grid results
    }
```

and here is Reports.js file:

```
    function ShowF() {
    $('#lnkShowFilter').hide();
    $('#divFilter').show();
    $('#lnkHideFilter').show();
    $('#divResult').hide();
    $('#MainContent_lblHeader').text("Reporting Filter");
}

function HideF() {
    $('#lnkShowFilter').show();
    $('#divFilter').hide();
    $('#lnkHideFilter').hide();
    $('#divResult').show();
    $('#').show();
    $('#MainContent_lblHeader').text("Report Result");
}

function SubmitF() {
   // alert("SubmitF");
    $('#lnkShowFilter').show();
    $('#divFilter').hide();
    $('#lnkHideFilter').hide();
    $('#divResult').show();
    $('#MainContent_lblHeader').text("Report Result");
}
```

Comment: Checking `Page.IsValid` only makes sense if you have a "CausesValidation" scenario - a button that submitted the form has its `CausesValidation` property set to True. This would automatically call `Page.Validate` and all Validation controls belonging to the same ValidationGroup would be checked for validity.

Comment: @Webruster, If I don't check 'if (Page.IsValid)' then even though the page validation occurs and momentarily (*) sign appears but the SubmitF is called and divFilter hides and the divResult shows, which we want to stop unless the page is valid. How can we achieve that?

Comment: you got a huge requriement over there ..

Answer (score 0):

well, I was able to solve the issue by using client-side validation. So I created a function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ValidateAndShowPopup() {
            if (Page_ClientValidate('grpSubmit')) {
                SubmitF();
            }
        }
```

And added both OnclientClick and OnClick to the submit button

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitReport" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitReport_Click" ValidationGroup="grpSubmit" OnClientClick="ValidateAndShowPopup()" CssClass="btn" />
```